# Weird behavior with CustomAdapter and CustomTextView

Tags: java, android, textview, android-arrayadapter

I have a custom `TextView` which I'm using in a custom `GridView` adapter. The custom `TextView` is using a custom font for translation purposes. This works fairly well in devices which have the locale installed by default.

However, in devices, in which the language is not installed, it is displaying a strange behavior. When the app loads the first time, the `TextViews` don't display with the custom font. However when I press the refresh button to reload the fragment, the `TextViews` display with the custom font.

I'm not sure why this is happening.

This is happening with all the custom `Adapters` in my application in which I'm using the custom `TextView`.

Pretty basic adapter:

```
public class CalendarWeekAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

    private String[] weekdays;
    Context mContext;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;

       public CalendarWeekAdapter(Context context, int firstDay)
       {
              mContext=context;
              mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
              weekdays = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.weekdays); 
       }
       public int getCount()
       {
              return weekdays.length;
       }
       public Object getItem(int position)
       {
              return position;
       }
       public long getItemId(int position)
       {
              return position;
       }
       public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
       {
              ViewHolder holder=null;
              if(convertView==null)
              {
                     convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.calendar_week, parent,false);
                     holder = new ViewHolder();
                     holder.txtWeekdays=(CustomTextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.weekdays);
                     if(position==0)
                     {                             
                           convertView.setTag(holder);
                     }
              }
              else
              {
                     holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
              }


             holder.txtWeekdays.setText(weekdays[position]);


             return convertView;
       }

}
class ViewHolder
{        
          CustomTextView txtWeekdays;                 
}
```

Basic CustomTextView:

```
public class CustomTextView extends TextView {
        public CustomTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
            super(context, attrs, defStyle);
            init();
        }

        public CustomTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
            super(context, attrs);
            init();
        }

        public CustomTextView(Context context) {
            super(context);
            init();
        }

        private void init() {
            if (!isInEditMode()) {
                setTypeface(Utils.getFont(getContext()));
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is may not be the answer, but i don't understand this if-statement:

```
                 holder.txtWeekdays=(CustomTextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.weekdays);
                 if(position==0)
                 {                             
                       convertView.setTag(holder);
                 }
```

Why is it there? All your newly inflated convertViews should have holder as their tag.
Just remove the 'if' around the convertView.setTag(holder):

```
          if(convertView==null)
          {
                 convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.calendar_week, null,false);
                 holder = new ViewHolder();
                 holder.txtWeekdays=(CustomTextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.weekdays);
                 convertView.setTag(holder);
          }
          ...
```

and see if this will improve or even fix your situation.

Comment: If I remove the `ifs` only from the around `convertView.setTag(holder)`, it still shows the same behavior i.e no font. But if I remove the `if` completely (`if (convertView == null)`), then it works surprisingly. Is it good practice to remove `if (convertView) == null`?

Comment: No, If you don't check for convertView == null, then you may run out of resources, creating too many views for your list items and bypassing view-recycling. Honoring the fact that convertView != null and re-using them is good practice.

Comment: What if you don't use the 'parent' parameter (I updated the example in my original answer by passing 'null' instead of 'parent' to the call to 'inflate')?

Comment: Did that. Same result i.e no font.

Comment: This is a head-scratcher! :) In your CustomTextView.init method, add a getTypeFace() to check if the setTypeFace(...) was successful. Debug that and see if the getTypeFace() call returns what you expect.

Comment: If I use normal `TextView` instead of the custom TextView and set typeface to it in `getView()`, it works. Not sure why it doesn't work with Custom TextView

Comment: Very very strange. It seems 'setTypeFace(...)' is called again after your call to "setTypeface(Utils.getFont(getContext()))". Try to add this to your CustomTextView: "@Override public void setTypeface(Typeface tf) { super.setTypeFace(tf); }" and put a breakpoint there and examine the stack to see what (framework) code may be calling this that you didn't expect.